# PHP stdObject - why property with name length > 30 is trimmed

Tags: php

I have an Object like this:

```
   $object = new stdClass();
   $object->ID= 1;
   $object->SendingThirdPartyAdvertisingFlag=1;
```

when I print the object with print_r($object ,true), the second property is trimmed to 30 symbols:

```
   stdClass Object
   (
    [ID] => 1
    [SendingThirdPartyAdvertisingFl] => 1
   )
```

At first I thought there is some config for this in the php.ini but had no success finding such. What causes this behaviour ?

UPDATE: PHP Version 5.4.45

Comment: It doesn't get trimmed for me (PHP 5.6.13) ...

Comment: it does not get trimmed for me too (PHP 7.01). Try use var_dump maybe it's issue with print_r? not sure but give it a try

Comment: When I try to fetch the property value, SendingThirdPartyAdvertisingFlag is not set, its SendingThirdPartyAdvertisingFl. Thats how I found this issue, I don`t think its print_r().